# Get path to directory, that next to project directory - JAVA

Tags: java, path

I need to create directory for image storing next to project root directory.

I know that project root directory path I can get this way:

```
String PROJECT_ROOT_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

If I do this way:

```
String PATH_TO_PACKAGE = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\imagesForTesting\\";
```

-- it will create directory in project root directory.

But I want to create directory not in, but **next to** project root directory.

> For example, I have PROJECT_ROOT_PATH = "D:\Work\Project"

And I need that new directory for images will be in:

> PATH_TO_PACKAGE =
>   "D:\Work\imagesForTesting";

In windows console it is pretty simple: to get level up you just have to use "cd .."

Is it possible to do such thing in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Java supports relative path such that you can use `..` in your path to access to the parent directory, in other words this can be done:

```
String PATH_TO_PACKAGE = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\..\\imagesForTesting\\";
```

**NB:** You can use `/` instead of `\\` to build your path, it will still work on windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Create a file with path as

```
String PROJECT_ROOT_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File file = new File(PROJECT_ROOT_PATH );
```

Step 2 : Check `file.isDirectory();`
Tests whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a directory.

3. `File parentFolder = file.getParentFile();`
   Returns the abstract pathname of this abstract pathname's parent, or null if this pathname does not name a parent directory.
4. Make new directory  in parent folder.